# C - Waiting for one child to terminate

Tags: c, fork, waitpid

I am creating multiple child processes in a loop.
Each child will do it's thing and anyone of them can end first.
(Not sure if relevant but: Each child also has a grandchild)

How do I wait for any child process to terminate and stop the others when one has finished ?

```
for(i=0; i<numberOfChildren; i++)
{
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: fork Failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /* Child Process */
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        /* Do your thing */
    }
    /* Parent process */
    else
    {
        childrenPid[i]=pid;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you parent is looping looking to see which child processes have exited, do a non-blocking waitpid() using WNOHANG and then look at the return value to see if a given child has exited or not -- I prefer this to wait for children to exit cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suspend the parent until one of its children terminates with the `wait` call and then `kill` the remaining children:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>

int status;
childpid = wait(&status)
```

Then, if you have stored the process ID of all children you created in an array, you can kill the remaining children:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

for(i = 0; i < nchildren; i++)
    if (children[i] != childpid)
        kill(children[i],SIGKILL)
```

where `nchildren` is an integer count of the number of children created and `children` is the array of pid_t of the children created.